# Definition of laplace to solve a unit step function equation

Tags: laplace-transform

i have watched some youtube videos on how to solve this equation, but im i now stuck. Can somebody tell me how to move on next and why?

$$f(t) = u(t-b)sin(a(t-b))$$
$$F(s) = \int_0^\infty \! e^{-st}u(t-b)sin(a(t-b)) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
$$= \int_b^\infty \! e^{-st}sin(a(t-b)) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
$$    = \int_0^\infty \! e^{-s(\frac{v}{a}+b)}sin(v) \, \mathrm{d}v.$$
$$    = e^{-sb}\int_0^\infty \! e^{-(\frac{s}{a})}sin(v) \, \mathrm{d}v.$$

Comment: You missed the distributive property in the exponent in the last line. With that fixed, use a Laplace transform you already know.

Comment: can you show me, im lost

Comment: If $v=a(t-b)$, then $dt=\frac{dv}{a}$. Also $v$ is missing from the exponential in the integrand of your last formula.

Comment: Okay, so i have come this far now. But i do not know how to use the lapace transform to move foraward. What do i do?
$$    = e^{-sb}\int_0^\infty \! e^{-(\frac{s}{a})v}sin(v) \, \mathrm{d}\frac{v}{a}.$$